# phpmysql update set while uploading image

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am really struggling trying to get something very simple achieved.

Essentially, I have an images table called `galleryimages` and a location on the server where images are stored. What I am trying to do is overwrite the source field for a given category in the table while the upload is going through.

My code will add the new image to the server, but not update the MySQL table for some reason (I can however add new lines to it although I want to keep the existing data in the table and simply change the "photo" field which locates the image).

My PHP is:

````php
<?php include 'dbc.php'; page_protect();

    if(!checkAdmin()) {header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
    }

    $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $host_upper = strtoupper($host);
    $login_path = @ereg_replace('admin','',dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    $path   = rtrim($login_path, '/\\');

    foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $get[$key] = filter($value);
    }

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $post[$key] = filter($value);
    }   
?>


<?php 
    if($_FILES['photo']) 
    {
        $target = "galleries/test/"; 
        $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

       $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']); 
        $pic = "galleries/test/" .(mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['photo']['name']));
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
    {
        mysql_query("update `galleryimages` set (`title`, `photo`) VALUES ('$title', '$pic')") ;     

        echo "Success"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo "Failure"; 

    }
    } 
?> 

And the HTML is:

```html
  </head>
  <body>

        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="addgallery1.php" method="POST">
          <table width="100%" border="2" cellpadding="5"class="myaccount">
             <tr>
               <td>Category: </td>
               <td><select name="title" id="select8">
                  <option value="Landscape Pots">Landscape Pots</option>

                      </select></td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>Image: </td>
               <td><input type="file" name="photo" /></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
               <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="CMSbutton" value="Add" /></td>
             </tr>
          </table>
        </form>

        </body>
        </html>
````

Now I am fairly sure the problem exists in the line:

```php
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
    {
        mysql_query("update `galleryimages` set (`title`, `photo`) VALUES ('$title', '$pic')") ;     
        echo "Success"; 
    }
```

but need some help to determine if this is indeed the case - and if so how I can get it to update the MySQL table - at the moment the PHP echoes Success but does not make any update to the "photo" column in MySQL.

Hope this makes sense and one of you coding geniuses can help me resolve this - its taken me hours of trial and error but still cant get it working!!!

thanks in advance to any and all help

JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some thing wrong here

```
 mysql_query("update `galleryimages` set (`title`, `photo`) VALUES ('$title', '$pic')") ;
```

it should be like

```
mysql_query("update `galleryimages` set `title`='$title', `photo`= '$pic'") ;
```

more info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL query is wrong:

```
update `galleryimages` set `title`='$title', `photo`='$pic'
```

But be warned:  This will update ALL rows in this table!  You should add a `WHERE` clause to update one specific row.